# How can I make Total Commander show "size on disk"?

Tags: filesystems, total-commander

Is there a way to make Total Commander show file sizes in "size on disk" instead of actual bytes in file?

Comment: None that I know of. The „size on disk” column is just Explorer’s rough estimate.

Comment: @kinokijuf: But it doesn't have to be. The filesystem *does* provide this information to programs.

Comment: A good description of the difference between size on disk and file size: http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-size-vs-size-on-disk/

Comment: Here is the solution https://superuser.com/a/1331024/106079

Answer (score 3):

Use `Ctrl+L`  (`File > Calculate Occupied Space...`).

This works on files as well as directories and shows both file size and [size on disk](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-size-vs-size-on-disk/).

Example: for the small file `No.bar` (26 bytes) in the totalcmd directory, you can see that it occupies 4K of space on disk -- i.e. that the Windows 7 filesystem uses 4K clusters.

[image: Screenshot showing result of running Calculate Occupied Space command]

Comment: It doesn't work this way sometimes.

Comment: Here is the solution https://superuser.com/a/1331024/106079

Comment: @BBK: very cool! :)