# How can I make Total Commander show actual size instead "size on disk" in the "size" column, while keeping the dynamic view (x.x k/M/G)?

Tags: windows, file-management, total-commander

TC shows "size on disk" in "size" column. I can use [ShellDetails](http://www.totalcmd.net/plugring/shelldetails.html) for instance, but I also want the dynamic size display (x.x k/M/G) that is not provided by the shell.

Comment: Did you search through or post your question on the support forum? http://www.ghisler.ch/board/index.php?language=english

Comment: @JanDoggen: thanks.. nothing there. I assume that requesting a feature won't really help in the next 3 years, since TC new features appearances are quite rare...

Comment: Not sure there's features left to put in TC ;-) It's already loaded with 'em.

Comment: I agree, @JanDoggen, except for one little feature - showing actual file size in dynamic format (x.x k/M/G)... :-P

Comment: Any luck so far?

Comment: @BBK - yes, apparently it works now. See FrancoisBotha's answer below: https://superuser.com/a/756415/149376

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make Total Commander show "size on disk"?](https://superuser.com/questions/467393/how-can-i-make-total-commander-show-size-on-disk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean you have set up a custom view and that you want dynamic sizes in the size column? I've done this by settings size to `[=tc.size.bkMG2]`

Comment: I rechecked it today, and it seems to work... It's funny, I do remember that it used to show size-on-disk... maybe they changed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize [WinScriptAdv plugin](http://totalcmd.net/plugring/WinScriptAdv.html). This is tested with Total Commander 9.12 x64.

To create a custom column with explorer rounded size display.

1. Download and install the plugin
2. Locate the plugin directory and modify options.ini
3. Add to ActiveScripts "|SizeOnDisk" if ActiveScripts not empty, if it
   is empty, then "ActiveScripts=SizeOnDisk"

**Code:**

```
[Script] 
ActiveScripts=MinutesAgo|CheckEncoding|Signature|SizeOnDisk

; List of scripts that will work together, returning their info in columns in one panel. 
; Separated by "|" - script1|script2 etc. One script can have multiple columns and display info with other
; scripts that also can be with multiple columns, all in one group of columns.
; You can add all scripts to ActiveScripts - it does not affect the performance (but takes more memory to 
; load and save script code), cause script runs only if you have the corresponding visible column in TC.  

[SizeOnDisk]
; File Size with explorer rounding in kB 
Script=SizeOnDisk.vbs
content=sizeondisk
extensions=*
FoldersPaths=0
```

4. Create a file  with the name SizeOnDisk.vbs in the sub folder scripts and paste the following code into this file. **I'm not an VBS programmer, so no guarantees, maybe someone with VBS knowledge might improve it**

**VBS Code:**

```
'==============================================================================
'Script for WinScriptAdv content plugin
'   content  - Size on Disk (Like Explorer column)
'==============================================================================
Set FSO  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
content  = Result(filename)
Set FSO  = Nothing

Function Result(pPath)
   If FSO.FileExists(pPath) Then

    Dim F : F = FSO.GetFile(pPath)
    Dim oShell, oFSO, oEnv, oNet
    Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oEnv = oShell.Environment("Process")
    Set oNet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    Dim sTempFile, aText, i, aInfo
    sTempFile = oFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(oFSO.GetTempName)
    oShell.Run "%comspec% /c compact " & Chr(34) & F & Chr(34) & " > " & Chr(34) & sTempFile & Chr(34), 0, True
    aText = Split(oFSO.OpenTextFile(sTempFile,1).ReadAll,vbCrLf)
    If oFSO.FileExists(sTempFile) Then oFSO.DeleteFile sTempFile, True 
    For i = 0 To UBound(aText)
        If InStr(aText(i),oFSO.GetBaseName(F)) Then
            aInfo = Split(Replace(aText(i),"=",":"), ":")
            If IsNumeric(Trim(aInfo(1))) Then
                Result = Trim(aInfo(1))
            End If
        End If 
    Next

      set F  = Nothing
   End If
End Function
```

5. Then Configure Custom Columns 
   [image: Custom Columns]
6. Add new custom columns configuration
   [image: Custom column configuration]
7. Then add new Column and place in caption field "*sizeondisk*" and in "*Field contents*" next text "***[=winscriptsadv.sizeondisk]***".
   [image]

Comment: Thank you for your effort! however it's too hacky.. But what really concerns me about this solution is its overhead - for highly populated directories, I'm afraid that it would take too much time to show all the folders/files in it.

Comment: You are absolutely right it WILL work much slower.

Comment: But you see, sometimes you need size on disk instead of “file size”. For example if you will use ntfs liks, file size will show you size of the file you are linked to, while size on disk show you “0”. Or another example: you have Dropbox or OneDrive with enabled “file smart sync” feature, so files appears to you as ordinary files (including size) but in reality the size on disk is 0, and file will be downloaded once when you trying to open it.

Comment: That’s why sometimes you might need to know “size on disk” instead of “reported file size”.